# See all goals in Experience Analytics

Tags: experience-analytics

All Goals list view control in `/sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/Conversions/Goals` shows only the latest 100 goals regardless of date range.

[image: All Goals table]

API request does not include any `keyTop` parameter, so it's not limited from the client:

```
/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/7EF1714E04E6455D9437FE55FFC483FC/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&dateFrom=26-03-2020&dateTo=23-06-2020&keyGrouping=by-key&keyOrderBy=visits-Desc
```

I also tried changing keysCount parameter value in core database's item that defines setting for list control, but the changes had no affect (no parameter was added). The settings item that I fiddled with:

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/Conversions/Goals/PageSettings/All goals - ExperienceAnalyticsListControl Parameters
```

If anyone knows how to view all goals (not just the latest 100), please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to patch the `ExperienceAnalytics.Api.KeysTopDefault` setting to modify the default number (100) of top keys results:

```
<!-- EXPERIENCE ANALYTICS - API - KEYS TOP DEFAULT
        The default value for keyTop query parameter.
        Default value: 100
    -->
<setting name="ExperienceAnalytics.Api.KeysTopDefault" value="100" />
```